# How to replace the android system image using a compressed file system?

Tags: android, android-emulator, filesystems, android-image, squashfs

Can one reduce the android images created using the `AVD` manager with a compressed file system?

Can one use `squashfs` to reduce the read-only files like `system.img`?

How to remove some of the kernel modules from that images?

In other words, I want to replace the system image, created using the `AVD` manager and used by the emulator, with the directories inside the image after compressing its contents to embed those directories in any device where I want to use the emulator.

Comment: I don't think your question is clear enough to explain what you want to do.  AN apk file is just a zip file, so if you want to modify it post creation you can-  you just need to sign it again after.  But its already a compressed file.

Comment: @GabeSechan I haven't mentioned any `apk`s. I just want to replace the image, created by the `avd` manager and used by the emulator, by the directories inside the image after compressing the contents to embed those directories in any device where I want to use the emulator. I hope it's clear now. Plz, Ask anything you want to clarify more.